# How to Resolve Wordpress AJAX Error - "my_ajax_obj not defined"?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to set up an AJAX call in Wordpress and I keep getting the console error: "my_ajax_obj not defined." Right now, I am building an LMS using a custom theme in Wordpress and when a video is watched, the goal is to trigger a php script to add to a user's meta data.

So far, this is what I have: when a lesson video is watched, the function

```
lesson_watched_call()
```

is called. I currently have my AJAX script in the file my-ajax-script.js and in that file, I have what is below.

```
function lesson_watched_call() {  
        console.log('Lesson watched fn called.')
        $.post(my_ajax_obj.ajax_url, {
            _ajax_nonce: my_ajax_obj.nonce,  // nonce
            action: "lesson_watched", // action call
            lastValue_php: lastValue // data
        });
    }
```

In my functions.php file, I have the enqueueing and localizing functions.

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
function my_enqueue() {

  wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my-ajax-script.js', array('jquery') );

  wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'my_ajax_object',
          array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
                 'nonce'    => wp_create_nonce( 'lesson_nonce_value' ),
          ) 
        );
}
```

My php function for the AJAX action is currently in my footer.php file.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_lesson_watched', 'add_lesson');
function add_lesson() {
    $lastValue_php = wp_unsplash( $_POST['lastValue_php'] );
      
    echo 'Howdy partner :)';
      
    wp_die(); // Ends all AJAX handlers
}
```

I have tried several formats, but all of them end up with the same console error saying that my_ajax_obj is not defined. Maybe there is something that I am overlooking?

Thank you for your time,

Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are defining in **php** `my_ajax_object` and you are trying to call in **js** `my_ajax_obj`

change your php code to:

```
wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'my_ajax_obj',
          array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
                 'nonce'    => wp_create_nonce( 'lesson_nonce_value' ),
          ) 
        );
```

Also, for enqueueing on the front end you should be using the [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/) hook. You are using the `admin_enqueue_scripts`.

your code should be:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
```

and your ajax function to show on front end as well add the [`wp_ajax_nopriv`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_nopriv_action/) hook

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_lesson_watched', 'add_lesson');
```

Comment: That is a good catch! I changed the variables so they are now the same, but I am receiving the same console error unfortunately.

Comment: is the `localized_script` being sent to the browser correctly? is the object there?

Comment: I am not seeing my_ajax_obj in a script tag in the HTML source, but I do see the src reference for my-ajax-script.js. I’m not sure if the localized_script is triggering correctly because it’s not showing up in the source files. Right now the enqueueing and localize_script are in the functions.php file so they should be accessible in my templates.php page.

Comment: is this on the wordpress front end or back end?

Comment: This is on the front end in the HTML page source. It’s kind of strange it’s not appearing.

Comment: you're calling enqueue for front end wrong. I updated my answer

Comment: Ok, now that is interesting. I tried using “wp_enqueue_scripts” and now I am not getting the “my_ajax_obj not defined” error, but I am getting a 400 (Bad Request) console error.

Comment: Also, it looks like the link it is following is “https://Ians-guides.local/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php,” but it should be “https://ians-guides.local/app/public/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php.” This is because I am currently running my site on Wordpress Local. Do you know how I would alter the ajax_url to include the “/app/public/“ file path? Also, thank you for your help with this.

Comment: No the first one is correct. you just have to define the ajax function to work on the front end as well. I updated my answer again

Comment: Hi, that worked in that I do not have any console errors now so thank you for your help!